# A integer triangle with the smallest perimeter and two rational trisectors of the same angle.

Tags: number-theory

Although I found this theorem [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_triangle#Integer_triangles_with_integer_n-sectors_of_all_angles), I didn't find any examples.

> There exist infinitely many non-similar triangles in which the three sides and the two trisectors of each of the three angles are integers.

If the condition is weakened, how to find an integer non-right triangle with two rational trisectors at the same angle?

Obviously, the case of right triangle is quite ordinary.

\begin{align*}
\tan\alpha&=\dfrac{7}{24}\\
\tan2\alpha&=\dfrac{2\tan\alpha}{1-\tan^2\alpha}=\dfrac{336}{527}\\
\tan3\alpha&=\dfrac{3\tan\alpha-\tan^3\alpha}{1-3\tan^2\alpha}=\dfrac{11753}{10296}\\
\end{align*}

Thus, what about integer non-right triangle?

> **My Question**
>
> What is a integer triangle with the smallest perimeter and two rational trisectors of the same angle?

[image]